# Elisp: How to accumulate function return into a list

Tags: shell, string, list

I have this small snippet of Elisp code that decodes kernel traces:

```
(defvar projbase "/my/proj/base")
(setq my_shell_output
  (substring 
   (shell-command-to-string (concat "/home/demetra/scripts/eaddrs2line.sh "
                                    projbase " " <each-line> ))
   0 -1))
```

How to write an Elisp function that calls this snippet of code for each line in a region and accumulate the results in a list ? The return is of format "**module-name function-name file-path/file-name line-num**".

After this is done I can work on the next task to show the list in a 
helm buffer where going to each line will open the **file-path/file-name** at **line-num**.

Comment: I chose this path because, the shell script can be used both from command line (for non-emacs users) as well as emacs editor. I'm trying to use it in emacs because that's where I view the source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few functions that might be useful here:

- `(buffer-substring-no-properties BEG END)` :: collect the buffer contents between `BEG` and `END`, two locations in the buffer (such as the beginning and end of a region), as a string
- `(split-string STRING "\n")` :: split STRING into a list of strings, broken at each linebreak
- `(mapcar FUNCTION LIST)` :: apply the function FUNCTION to every element in a LIST, and collect the results in a list.

In your case, something like this:

```
(mapcar (lambda (X) <SHELL-COMMAND-TO-STRING on X>)
        (split-string (buffer-substring-no-properties BEG END) "\n"))
```

Replacing `<SHELL-COMMAND-TO-STRING on X>` with the appropriate code. You'll still need to figure out how to get the values of BEG and END (maybe using `(interactive "r")`), and also you'll need to store/use the list returned by the `mapcar`.

Comment: thank you your snippet was very useful. Is there anyway I can ignore empty lines in selected region during (buffer-substring-no-properties BEG END)?